# Rails cache apparently not invalidated

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My application is set up to use memcached:

```
# production.rb
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :mem_cache_store, Figaro.env.memcache_server || '127.0.0.1'
```

Several pages of the application are handled by one Elasticsearch query; for example, users may click a "All product X/Y/Z" button before doing any specific filtering. I thought I could handle that by using the query as a cache key. For example:

```
cache_string = q.to_query('q') + fields.to_query('fields') + per_page.to_s + page.to_s + sort_clause.to_query('sort')
cache_value = OpenSSL::Digest::SHA256.base64digest(cache_string)
Rails.cache.fetch("#{cache_value}/search_products", expires_in: 4.hours) do
  ::Product.search(q ? q : "*",
                   where: where_clause,
                   fields: fields,
                   match: :word_middle,
                   per_page: max_per_page(per_page) || 30,
                   page: page || 1,
                   order: sort_clause,
                   aggs: aggs,
                   misspellings: {below: 5}
        )
end
```

But, if I click the X/Y/Z buttons the number of products does not change, and it should.
Have I misunderstood something about how this is supposed to work?

N.B. this is an API-only application.

Comment: Because of `"#{cache_value}/search_products"`. My understanding is that it's a key which would allow me to cache different search results. Am I mistaken? If so, please explain how - thanks.

Comment: It must be changing every time the query is run, because the query parameters will differ.

Comment: Normally I'd agree, but I have failed to spot anything of use.